# Can I avoid "Hotspotting" issue in Habse table by "Pre-splitting" region-servers?

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, bigdata

If not can you suggest how to improve distribution across all regional servers(without pre-splitting)?

Comment: Your title states that you want to pre-split, but your question body states that you don't want to pre-split. Please could you clarify which one you mean?

Comment: @BenWatson thank you for your replay.I want to know, how to distribute data across all regional-servers without using pre-splitting option?                                                 I tried using Salting, Hashing and Reversing the Key issue is not resolved.

Comment: @SiddeshHK Pre-splitting is not direct answer to "hotspot" issue.  Using pre-splitting you create as many region as you expect to have according to your data distribution.  But if your keys(even if it salted or hashed) falls into one region, you face hotspot again.

If you not pre-split and even your keys have a good distribution, at a start, table will contain only 1 region until it reach max size. After that region will be split and may be moved to another RegionServer.  All start again until new regions will reach max sizes, split and redistributed between servers again.